# how to get the key with the highest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this which contains random numbers as key and their prime divisors as values.

```
d= {123: 2, 43: 1, 54: 2, 12: 2, 76: 2, 84: 3, 98: 2, 678: 3, 543: 2, 231: 3}
```

I want to get the number with the highest value. if more than one key has the same value it should print out the biggest.
for instance, here the numbers 84,678 and 231 all have the highest values and I want 678 to be printed out not 84 or 231.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `max` and as comparator key a multi-factor that take first the `value` (`pair[1]`) then the `key` (`pair[0]`). The final `[0]` is to retrieve only the key, not the pair

```
values = d = {123: 2, 43: 1, 54: 2, 12: 2, 76: 2, 84: 3, 98: 2, 678: 3, 543: 2, 231: 3}
max_key = max(values.items(), key=lambda pair: (pair[1], pair[0]))[0]
print(max_key) # 678
```

A more performant code (`~30%`)

```
from operator import itemgetter 
max_key = max(values.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0))[0]
```

Comment: Or likely slightly faster `>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {123: 2, 43: 1, 54: 2, 12: 2, 76: 2, 84: 3, 98: 2, 678: 3, 543: 2, 231: 3}
#sort values in ascending order
d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
#sort keys in ascending order
d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
#convert it to list of keys and get the last one(max in keys and values)
print(list(d)[-1]) # 678
```

Comment: this works properly only if the highest key has the highest value. what if 84 had 4. it prints out 678 again